# Component Not Re-rendering on clicking of a Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using Link property of react to goto the same url, But with the diffrent param. But my api is not calling again as i put the api call part in the **componentDidMount()**.On Click of a url my url param change. Below is the code.

```
componentDidMount(){ 
   let profile_id = window.localStorage.getItem('profile_id');
   if(profile_id && profile_id!==''){
     this.props.fetchSingleProfile(profile_id)          
   }
}
```

First time, api call and data rendered successfully. Below is how i am using Link.

```
<Link to={this.userId}>Next</Link>
```

Now on click of link,I am successfully routed to the give url, But as i mentioned "**Component is rendering again on successfully routing, But api is not calling again**". Is there any thing in react, which is aware of it, my url is changed, Now call the api again.

**Note:** Can i use any lifecycle method like: componentWillReceiveProps, But i don't want to call the api again.

Comment: Can you please add a code example to your question showing us how you are doing this?

Comment: i have edited the code.

Comment: so it's not only route the same. the only parameter is also equal. why do you even use `<Link>` here? something like `<button onClick={this.loadData}>` would reload the data just fine.

Comment: OnClick of a Link, I am calling the api again, But that is the wrong approach, which i am following.Is there any lifecycle method, which help me to call the api again?

Answer (score 1):

> But my api is not calling again as i put the api call part in the componentDidMount().

You have same route, so the same `<Route>` is rendered. All nested components stay the same so instead of remounting they are just updated.

You have few possible ways to handle that:

1. Fetch data not only on `componentDidMount` but also on `componentDidUpdate`
2. Use `key` to [remount component](https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e)

It cannot be done with just `react-router`'s `<Link />` since [it is not actually its responsibility](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. can you please show me the example as it's urgent.

Comment: you are saying, i need to use componentDidUpdate and call the api again.If i need to call the api again then i can call a function onClick of it, in which the api will call.But this is the wrong approach.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` gets update even for a slight change, should we keep some `state` variable to check if the component should fetch data in `componentDidUpdate` as well?

Comment: @TheCoder do you want check both `props` and `state` in `cDU`? I'm not sure if I follow your question